# How to use nodemailer to send email notification upon successful registration

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

I want when the user successfully registers, an email will be automatically sent to the registration email.

Why when I register it shows "Failed to create user"

Can anyone tell me where I went wrong?

Here, after successful registration, it will send a welcome email with an account activation link in the form "/user/activated-account/:User_ID" with User_ID being `User_ID` CHAR(36) DEFAULT (UUID()) PRIMARY KEY when clicked by the user can activate the account

my code

sendActivationEmail.js

```
import nodemailer from "nodemailer";

export async function sendActivationEmail(userEmail) {
  try {
    const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
      service: "gmail",
      auth: {
        user: "test@gmail.com",
        pass: "test",
      },
    });

    const emailContent = {
      from: "test@gmail.com",
      to: userEmail,
      subject: "Activate Your Account",
      html: `
          <p>Dear User,</p>
          <p>Click the following link to activate your account:</p>
          <a href="">Activate Account</a>
        `,
    };

    // Send the email
    await transporter.sendMail(emailContent);

    console.log("Activation email sent successfully");
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Send Activation Email Error:", error);
    throw new Error("Failed to send activation email");
  }
}

export default { sendActivationEmail };
```

register

```
export async function register(req, res) {
  try {
     const getRandomAvatar = () => {
      const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * avatars.length);
      return avatars[randomIndex].avatar;
    };

    const { Username, Email, Password } = req.body;

    // Check Email is not empty
    if (!Email) {
      return res.status(400).send("Email cannot be empty.");
    }

    // Check Username is not empty
    if (!Username) {
      return res.status(400).send("Username cannot be empty.");
    }

    // Check if email already exists in the database
    const emailExistQuery = `SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE LOWER(Email) = LOWER(?)`;
    const emailAlready = await connection.query(emailExistQuery, [Email]);

    // Check if Username already exists in the database
    const usernameExistQuery = `SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE LOWER(Username) = LOWER(?)`;
    const usernameAlready = await connection.query(usernameExistQuery, [
      Username,
    ]);

    // Check if there is any user with the given email or username
    if (emailAlready.length > 0 && emailAlready[0].length > 0) {
      return res.status(400).send("Email already exists");
    } else if (usernameAlready.length > 0 && usernameAlready[0].length > 0) {
      return res.status(400).send("Username already exists");
    } else {
      // Hash the password
      const salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10);
      const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(Password, salt);

      // Insert the user into the database
      const insertUserQuery = `
        INSERT INTO USERS (Username, Email, Password, AVATAR)
        VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?;

      const newUserValues = [
        Username,
        Email,
        hashedPassword,
        getRandomAvatar(),
      ];

      const result = await connection.query(insertUserQuery, newUserValues);

      
      if (result.affectedRows === 1) {
        const user_ID = result[0].insertId; 

       
        await sendActivationEmail(Email);

        return res
          .status(200)
          .send("User has been created. Activation email sent.");
      } else {
        console.error("Failed to create user. Result:", result);
        return res.status(500).send("Failed to create user");
      }
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Registration Error:", error);
    return res.status(500).send({ error: error.message });
  }
}
```